# Neomutt Show Email Body as preview

Tags: linux, email, mutt

I am trying to switch away from thunderbird into Neomutt but I need some ability to see the contents of emails without manually opening a pager. I receive way too many emails that are extremely short or don't have useful subjects  Either showing the body next to the subject in the Index (like Gmail) or opening a pager on whichever message is currently highlighted (like Thunderbird) would work although I'd definitely prefer the former.

Comment: "opening a pager on whichever message is currently highlighted" — you mean pressing return?

Comment: Pressing return opens a pager for the currently highlighted message but it needs to be done for every single message and the navigation keys now navigate the pager instead of the index. I want (if pagers are going to be how I get a preview) for me navigating to any message to automatically open a pager without taking focus away from the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot display body content in the index as it's in GMail. But you can easily navigate between messages using any of following solutions.

I assume you use default bindings, but I'll cite the function names in italic also. Both solutions relies on using built-in pager.

## Solution #1 unset pager_stop

`set pager_stop = no`

[pager_stop documentation](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference#3-238-%C2%A0pager_stop)

`<enter>` to *display-message* in pager, then pressing `<space>` *next-page* will take you to the next message when you reach the end of the current one. On short messages where there's not an option to scroll it acts on the first space hit.

## Solution #2 set pager_index_lines

Keep index visible with `$pager_index_lines` number of lines when you display a message in pager.

```
set pager_index_lines = 10 # set to whatever you like
```

[pager_index_lines documentation](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference#3-237-%C2%A0pager_index_lines)

With this settings You can `<enter>` to *display-message* and use `j` *next-entry* and `k` *previous-entry* to select messages in the index.

---

see both solutions in action:
[image: asciicast]

Comment: Thank you! I was actually most of the way there with the set page_index_lines setting but I had no idea I could move to the next message with that (by default next-entry is actually bound to `J` when in the pager)

Comment: There are multiple bindings for next-entry in menus: these are the defaults index (J), pager (J) and generic (j). Any of these works even when you unbound the others.